# How to iteratively extract feature using sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, nlp

I have a sqlite3 database containing many text data. I want to extract the text and convert them into term-frequency matrix using '*CountVectorizer*' or '*HashingVectorizer*'. The way I can think of is to use '*fetchall' function of 'sqlite3.*.cursor'.

The problem is that the dataset is too big. I am wondering if there is a way to extract features and convert to matrix iteratively?

```
# extract text data using 'fetchall'
conn=sqlite3.connect('text.db')
c=conn.cursor()
c_exe=c.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
text_tuple=c_exe.fetchall()
text=[item[0] for item in text_tuple]

# convert the text into tf-matrix
vectorizer=CountVectorizer()
Y=vectorizer.fit_transform(text)

# if there's a way to do it iteratively, e.g. 'modified_vectorizer'
for text in c_exe:
    Y=modified_vectorizer()
```

Comment: HashingVectorizer is a stateless transformer, so it doesnt need to fit data. It can be used easily iterating the rows.

Comment: @VivekKumar Can you give some sample code? If iterate it, the matrix from previous iteration will be overwrite by the current iteration matrix.